# Android SDK : Can I convert InputStream to FileInputStream?

Tags: java, android

I need to streaming media and video from samba server to android, and I use JCIFS to get inputstream from samba file.
But in MediaPlayer only can use fileinputstream.getFD() to play media.

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(convertedFile);
mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

Toast.makeText(this, "Success, Path has been set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

I can't getFD() from inputstream so that I need to convert inputstream to fileinputstream...
Please give me a suggest,  or there hava others solution to streaming media from samba server ?

This is my SmbFileInputStream, but it's not equals than fileinputstream

```
SmbFileInputStream f = new SmbFileInputStream(new SmbFile(filePath,auth));
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` pipe using `createPipe()`. You would copy bytes from your `FileInputStream` into an `OutputStream` on your end of the pipe, and give the `FileDescriptor` from `getFileDescriptor()` to `MediaPlayer`. Whether this will work or not with your desired stream is a completely different matter, but it's the only way I know of to get a `FileDescriptor` that represents arbitrary content.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) demonstrating this, in the context of implementing `openFile()` on a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I need convert smbfileinputstream to fileinputstream, is it possible?